# Curve of minimal length intersecting all lines which intersect the unit disk

Tags: geometry

I was bored and this problem popped into my head: What is the shortest curve or set of curves with shortest combined length which will intersect any line intersecting the unit disk? In more formal terms:

> Let $\mathbb D$ be the unit disk, i.e. the set of points $\{ p \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \| p \| \le 1 \}$.
>
> Let $\delta(p)$ be the set of all lines thought the point $p$, i.e. $\{ \{ p + t  v \mid t \in \mathbb R ) \} \mid v \in \mathbb (\mathbb R^2 \setminus (0, 0) \}$
>
> Let $\sigma$(t) be a *well-behaved*[0] function of type $[0, 1] \to \mathbb R^2$. This function describes the curve or curves we are looking for.
>
> Let $image(\sigma)$ be the *image* of the function $\sigma$.
>
> Let $L(\sigma)$ be the arc-length of the curve of a function $\sigma$.
>
> A point $p$ is called *supported* if every line though it has at least one point in common with $\sigma$, i.e. $l \in \delta(p) \Rightarrow l \cap image(\sigma) \ne \emptyset$.
>
> The function $\sigma$ is said to be *supporting* the unit disk if it supports every point of it, i.e. $p \in \mathbb D \Rightarrow p \text{ is } supported$.
>
> We are looking for a function $\sigma$ *supporting* the unit disk with minimal arc length $L(\sigma)$.

Has this or a similar problem already been solved?

For example: The unit circle is a solution for which it is quite intuitive to see that it satisfies the condition of supporting the unit disk. Its arc length is $2 \pi$. Restricting myself to line segments and circular arcs, these are some of the solutions I found:

[image]

Arc length: $4 \sqrt 2 \approx 5.65685$

[image]

Arc length: $\frac{3 \pi}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \approx 5.4195$

[image]

Arc length: $4.81893$

[0]: *Well-behaved* is intentionally vague language because I assume that the exact definition of what functions are allowed might influence what solutions can be found, how hard it is to find and whether there are solutions at all. I think solutions or problem analysis using any conditions on the function are interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you problem correctly, it is the same problem as the one which I know from the following papers, where they call it „opaque sets“. The papers and the references in them might give you an idea of what is known and what is still open in this area. The question about the unit disk is as far as I know answered [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2322935?seq=1).

[Paper 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3894)
[Paper 2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2218)